# Print Option doesn't work correctly in crystal report viewer 2013 on asp.net Project

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I enabled report viewer print button for printing purpose.
the problem is when i clicked on print button `print to pdf` dialog appears,
I have installed printer on both server and my PC so there is no problem with printer availability.

Answer (score 0):

the hint in the print dialog shows the instruction of print

> The viewer must export to PDF to print.

Comment: I know but I want to open the print dialog.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way it`s better and more efficient than opening the viewer and print it in PDF format

```
  cryRpt.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, True, "ExportedReport")
```

the thing is that when binding the report, your datasource will disposed automatically then when you are trying to print it to PDF from the viewer there will be no datasource.... but there is a solution you need to find at which event the viewer is disposing the datasource and prevent it of doing such.

Comment: my dear. I need to printing client side from Crystal report viewer direct to print.